# feynmp for mixing vertex between two photons

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp

I'm trying to draw a feynman diagram like the one in the picture in latexit, but currently it doesn't output anything at all. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
% !TEX program = pdflatexmk
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
\begin{fmfgraph*}(180,120)
    \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfv{label=$e^-$,label.distance=10}{i1}
    \fmfv{label=$e^+$,label.distance=10}{i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
    \fmfv{label=$e^+$,label.distance=10}{o2}
    \fmfv{label=$e^-$,label.distance=10}{o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,a,i1}
    \fmf{fermion}{o1,b,o2}
    \fmf{photon,label={$A'$}}{a,c}
    \fmf{photon,label={$\gamma$}}{c,b}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile} 
\end{document}
```

The picture i'm trying to copy is this:
[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: What happened to \begin{document} and \end{document} ?

Comment: I think it's contained within the LaTeXiT package. It's not shown in the preamble anyway, but since I always use LaTeXiT for images like this and I haven't changed the preamble I don't think that's the problem